# Conflicting boolean values of an empty JavaScript array

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain why the following two statements both evaluate as **true**?

```
[] == false
```

and

```
!![]
```

This question is purely out of curiosity of why this happens and not about how to best test if an array is empty.

Comment: If you really want to get your hands dirty, take a look at section 11.9.1 (*"The Equals Operator =="*) and Section 8.7.1 (*"GetValue(V)"*) in [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm). And this would be another great example of why `== true` and `== false` are generally not ideal style. :-)

Comment: Actually, using == or != is never good style. Always use === or !==, and cast the operands by hand.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The first one:

```
[] == false
```

The `==` operator does type conversion to its operands, in this case the both sides are converted to Number, the steps taken on the [Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) would be:

- object == boolean
- object == number
- string == number
- number == number

In code:

```
[] == false; // convert false to Number
[] == 0;     // convert [] to Primitive (toString/valueOf)
"" == 0;     // convert "" to Number
0  == 0;     // end
```

The second comparison, `[]` is converted to primitive, their `valueOf` and `toString` methods are executed, but since `valueOf` on Array objects, returns the object itself (is inherited from `Object.prototype`), then the `toString` method is used.

At the end as you see, both operands are converted to Number, and both yield zero, for example:

```
Number([]) == 0;
Number(false) == 0;
```

And empty array produces zero when converted to Number because its string representation is an empty string:

```
[].toString(); // ""
```

And an empty string converted to Number, yields zero:

```
+""; // 0
```

Now, the double negation (`!![]`) produces true because all object instances are truthy:

```
![];  // false, [] is truthy
!![]; // true, negation
```

The only values that are *falsey* are:

- `null`
- `undefined`
- `0`
- `NaN`
- `""` (an empty string)
- `false`

Anything else will produce `true` when converted to Boolean.

See also:

- [JavaScript Coercion Tool](http://jscoercion.qfox.nl/)

Comment: Very interesting.  Thanks for the detailed description and sharing those links.

Comment: Whoops, looks like I answered the same question in the same way.  Didn't notice until someone marked that question a duplicate of this one.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10556035/2653

Answer (score 1):

[] == false

In this case, the type of the left-hand side is object, the type of the right-hand side is boolean. When object is compared to (== The Abstract Equality Comparison) boolean, Javascript first converts the boolean to a number, yielding 0. Then it converts the object to a "primitive", yielding the empty string "". Next it compares the empty string to 0. The empty string is converted to a number, yielding 0, which is numerically equal to the 0 on the right-hand side, so the result of the entire expression is true.

Ref:
http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3
11.9.3 The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm

!![]

In this case Javascript converts the object to the boolean true, then inverts it, resulting in false.

Comment: :Please be more descriptive about your solution. Refer:[How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)