# Using expressions and logical operators in function arguments

Tags: javascript

What does it mean to have expressions with logical operators passed as an argument to a function?!

For example:

```
myFunc(expr_1 || expr_2 || expr_3);
```

Is it equivalent to the following?!:

```
var expr_all = expr_1 || expr_2 || expr_3;
myFunc(expr_all);
```

And if so, how is it supposed to work especially if all three expressions evaluate to strings (as opposed to booleans), or if `expr_1` is `undefined` or something?!

Thanks.

Comment: This will pass the first truthy value (or just the last one, when none of them are truthy) to the function, between those 3 variables. For example, `myFunc(false || null || "foo")`, `"foo"` will be passed

Comment: if the string is blank, it's false, otherwise, it's true.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> `myFunc(expr_1 || expr_2 || expr_3); Is it equivalent to the`
>   following?!:
>
> `var expr_all = expr_1 || expr_2 || expr_3; myFunc(expr_all);`

Yes it is.  It will pass the first truthy value to the function.

Truthy values are values that are not `false`,`null`,`NaN`,`""`, `0`,or `undefined`

This works because `||` is the logical or statement.  It will return the value of the first object from left to right that is truthy.  Otherwise it will return false.

See these examples:

```
"a" || "b" //"a"

"" || "b" //"b"

"" || "" //""

"" || undefined  //undefined

"" || [] // []
```

Comment: And `[]` (empty list) and `NaN` (not-a-number, the result of an number operation that can't have a number as output like `5 - "a"`).

Comment: Yeah hit enter before I meant to.  @Fritz, [] is truthy

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Yeah, objects are truthy. You might be thinking of Python (if you use it, or some other language), where empty objects aren't truthy

Comment: @ben336 I know you knew, I just wanted to make sure you had the complete list for anyone who sees

Comment: @ben336 Thanks, that makes it very clear now. I was going to change it but it looks just fine now with that explanation.

Comment: It also might be worth mentioning if there are no truthy values, it just passes the last one

Comment: `[] == false` gives `true`, so is it truthy or falsey?

Comment: @ChuckUgwuh yeah your code is (semantically at least) fine as is.  Not enough information to tell you whether its doing what its supposed to of course.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen when comparing an object to a boolean using `==`, js tries to convert the object to a number with js. For the empty set that number is 0.  But it is not generally falsy

Comment: @FritsvanCampen In short: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491605/javascript-empty-array-seems-to-be-true-and-false-at-the-same-time

Comment: Ah, so it does a `toString` .. weird. Don't use `==` kids.

Comment: @ben336 `"" || ""` doesn't produce `false` (neither does the next example). They produce the second operand

Answer (score 3):

`||` isn't a comparison operator. It is a shorthand conditional. If the expression on the left evaluates to true then it is returned, otherwise the expression on the right is returned.

If an undefined variable is evaluated before the evaluation completes: `undefinedVar || 3` then the entire evaluation fails and an error occurs.

Your 2 code samples are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

They're equivalent (if you ignore the intermediate variable).

JavaScript's logical OR operator short-circuits, so it'll break at the first truthy value in that chain of ORs and return it. If none of them are truthy, the last one will be returned.

Truthy values are the opposite of falsy values, which are `0`, `''`, `false`, `null`, `undefined`, etc. If one of those variables happens to be `0`, you may run into problems.