# Boolean evaluation of JavaScript arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean-expression

I ran across an interesting bug the other day. I was testing an array to see if it evaluated to Boolean false, however just directly evaluating it always returned true:

```
> !![]
  true
```

Okay, so basically any array I put in there will be `true` regardless, right? I run this in the JavaScript console just for fun:

```
> [] == true
  false
```

What is going on here?

Comment: About these kind of problems, I think you would enjoy this talk: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Comment: You might want to take a look at this question for your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491605/javascript-empty-array-seems-to-be-true-and-false-at-the-same-time

Comment: Have you looked at my answer?

Answer (score 3):

It has to do with the [The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) versus the algorithm used to tranform a value to a boolean.

By looking at [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3), we can see that the point number **9.** is the only one that defines what should be happening when **Type(left side value) is Object**. However it's specifying that the **right side value has to be either String or Number**.

> 9 . If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String or Number,
>   return the result of the comparison ToPrimitive(x) == y.

Looking at `[] == true`:

`typeof []` is `'object'` so we are fine, but `typeof true` is not `'string'` or `'number'`, it is `'boolean'`, so it fallback to the last statement, point number **10.**

> 10 . Return false.

However `!![]` translates into `!!Boolean([])`, and since `[]` is a thruty value (objects are), it's the same as writing `!!true`, which returns `true`.