# Should an empty array return true?

Tags: javascript

I thought `[]` should return `false` when checked by `!![]` but I tried it and it returns `true`.

Is it correct or does it depend on a browser?

Comment: with google I get a million answers on this: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=javascript+empty+array+truthy did you try google?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491605/empty-arrays-seem-to-equal-true-and-false-at-the-same-time

Comment: `![].length && "empty array"`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146176/javascript-empty-array-evaluates-to-true-in-conditional-structures-why-is

Comment: look at this. I've tried bing: they also have answers: https://www.bing.com/search?q=javascript+empty+array+truthy&go=Senden&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=javascript+empty+array+truthy&sc=0-11&sp=-1&sk=&ghc=1&cvid=6738d1e962ed4e7f891385d50858dfd2

Comment: PHP programmers may expect intuitively [] (and '0') to be false, but nope - that's javascript, those are true.