# Why is Boolean([]) true in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am going through JavaScript: The Definitive Guide. In it it says

```
Boolean([]) // => true
```

But I don't understand the logic behind this. Why is the boolean of an empty array `true`?

Comment: What do you mean *"why"*? Per e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean only zero and `NaN` values, empty strings, `false`, `null` and `undefined` are considered false-y. Other languages make different decisions, e.g. an empty collection is false-y [in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

Comment: Empty arrays are _falsy_ in PHP but this is JavaScript and it has its own rules.

Comment: Same question. You can find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146176/why-do-empty-javascript-arrays-evaluate-to-true-in-conditional-structures/73275067#73275067

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ECMAScript specification defines how values are cast to booleans, per the abstract `ToBoolean` operation: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toboolean

That operations includes a single entry for object input:

> Object:   Return `true`.

Thus, when you supply any object to `Boolean`, including an array (even an empty one), you'll get a `true` value back,

Comment: I think the "why" here is referring to the decisions behind choosing to make “Boolean([]) === true”, not “where in the spec is this behavior described”.

Javascript didn’t just evolve out of the dirt. Someone had to think that an empty array being truthy had advantages over an empty array being falsy.

Answer (score 1):

Array is considered as an object, even if it's empty. That's why the `Boolean` has a value, means it's `true`.
Only `false`, `null` or `undefined` are values which will return `false`.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript (and other languages) have a concept of 'truthy' and 'falsey' values.

You said you're from a C++ background, so we can make it analogous to something like this in C++:

```
if (ptr) { }
```

which is falsey if `ptr` is null, and truthy otherwise.

It just so happens that in JavaScript, arrays - even empty ones, among many other things - are considered to be truthy.