# Why !document.querySelectorAll not working for multiple id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have this working , but i need to add an additional element so i switched to SelectorAll , but it doesn't work

This is working

```
if(!document.getElementById('body_options_45')) {
//Do Stuff
}
```

When i add a 2nd ID and switch to selectorALl , it stops working

```
if(!document.querySelectorAll('#body_options_45, #body_options_113')) {
   //Do Stuff
}
```

What am i missing here ?

Comment: You are missing what `querySelectorAll()` returns. Look it up in the docs and you'll see, and will understand how to make it work.

Answer (score 4):

`querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`. You will need to check the `length` like this: `if (!document.querySelectorAll('#body_options_45, #body_options_113').length)`

Answer (score 0):

[querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a **NodeList**. [NodeLists are not arrays](https://gomakethings.com/nodelists-vs-arrays/) but, in this particular case, the behavour is the same: empty arrays and empty NodeLists are both [truthy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19146230/11298742).

```
![] //returns false
```

```
!emptyNodeList //returns false
```

To check if your NodeList is empty or not, use the `length` property:

```
if(document.querySelectorAll('#body_options_45, #body_options_113').length===0) {
   //do stuff
}
```