# Why is an empty array equal to false?

Tags: javascript, type-coercion

I was reading the “Types and Grammar” section of the *You Don’t Know JS* book and I am having a hard time understanding this.

Why is an empty array equal to `false`?

```js
console.log(false == []); // true
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146176/javascript-empty-array-evaluates-to-true-in-conditional-structures-why-is

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Empty arrays seem to equal true and false at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491605/empty-arrays-seem-to-equal-true-and-false-at-the-same-time) — second result for “js empty array equals false” in Google (the other link is the first result).

Comment: @pramodsingh What? This has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: But it returns `true` for me !

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Answer (score 3):

When you do `[] == false`, behind the scenes the `Array.prototype.toString` method is called with that empty array as its `this` context, which returns the empty string `""` and the empty string is a falsy value in JavaScript.

Comment: @hev1 [The specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/) calls it “the empty string” _because there’s only one_.

Comment: @user4642212 Thanks for informing me.