# IF statement to identify 'null' in loop being ignored

Tags: javascript

I have the following loop which I have put together and is working (up to a point):

```
 for (var i = 0; i < dataIn.length; i++) {
  if (dataIn.YourName = [] ) {
      var modifiedName = dataIn[i].YourName.replace(/ \([\s\S]*?\)/g, '');
      dataIn[i].YourName = modifiedName; 
       
     }
     
    else {
 console.log('Do Nothing');
    }
 }
```

However, I run into an error when the content from the API source is empty (null).
Console error: Cannot read property 'replace' of null

As a result I have tried to update my loop to only run if the information is NOT null or undefined (see below), but it is being ignored and still trying to run.

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataIn.length; i++) {
  if (dataIn.YourName !== null && dataIn.YourName !== '' ) {
      var modifiedName = dataIn[i].YourName.replace(/ \([\s\S]*?\)/g, '');
      dataIn[i].YourName = modifiedName; 
       
     }
     
    else {
 console.log('Do Nothing');
    }
 }
```

Sample data from the API.

What works:

```
"YourName": "John Citizen",
```

What throws the console error:

```
"YourName": null,
```

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator, you want `==` or `===`. But your `if` condition will still not work as expected because this is not how you check if a variable stores an empty array.

Comment: We need to have an idea of how `dataIn` looks like

Comment: _"is NOT null or undefined"_ - `'' !== undefined`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a standard function to check for null, undefined, or blank variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first address an issue here. This line:

```
if (dataIn.YourName = [] ) {
```

Will *always* evaluate true. You are assigning an empty array to your `YourName` property and then using that assignment in an `if` - [empty arrays are always truthy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146176/javascript-empty-array-evaluates-to-true-in-conditional-structures-why-is).

As to how you've tried to correct it, you're checking initially `dataIn.YourName` but then trying to read `dataIn[i].YourName` - you need to be consistent. I suspect what you want is:

```
 if (dataIn[i].YourName !== null && dataIn[i].YourName !== '' ) {
    var modifiedName = dataIn[i].YourName.replace(/ \([\s\S]*?\)/g, '');
    dataIn[i].YourName = modifiedName;        
 }
```

Comment: Thank you Jamiec. Answer is obvious now that you pointed it out. Appreciated the help and the prompt reply. Take care!