# reactjs - else part of statement doesn't work?

Tags: html, reactjs

I am trying to make the following code work:

```
{
   (this.props.fill_sett_list ? (this.props.fill_sett_list.map(fill_sett_list_item => (
                                <td>{fill_sett_list_item.filled_val}</td> ))) : 
                      (<td><a href="#/filledsetting"><button className='btn btn-primary btn-sm'>FILL</button></a></td>))
}
```

Unable to understand why the second part i.e. the `else` doesn't show up. It becomes blank.

The `reducer`:

```
fillReducer
   fill_sett_list(pin): []
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146176/why-do-empty-javascript-arrays-evaluate-to-true-in-conditional-structures

Comment: Got it working from the answer mentioned by @Nikki9696