# node js callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, function

I am new to nodeJs. In my code I have a asynchronous function for finding records from mongoDB.

```
var restify = require('restify');
var mongojs = require('mongojs');

var ip_addr = '127.0.0.1';
var port    =  '8080';

var server = restify.createServer({
    name : "signapp"
});

server.use(restify.queryParser());
server.use(restify.bodyParser());
server.use(restify.CORS());

var connection_string = '127.0.0.1:27017/signapp';
var db = mongojs(connection_string, ['signapp']);

var docDetails = db.collection("SIGN_DOCUMENT_DETAILS");

var PATH = '/documents'
server.post({path : PATH  + '/:search', version: '0.0.1'}, searchDoc);

function searchDoc(req, res, next)
{
 var criteria = {};
 criteria.DOC_NAME = req.params.DOC_NAME;

  if (criteria.DOC_NAME !== '' || criteria.DOC_NAME !== null)
  {
    docDetails.find({DOC_NAME : criteria.DOC_NAME}, function(err, users){
    if( err || !users){
       console.log("No record found");
    }
    else {
        console.log('record found');
    }
    });
  }

}
```

In my request I pass a string parameter. I am getting 'record found' response in my console when the condition is matched.
But the problem is I am getting response in console as 'record found' even when the find condition fails. I tried a lot ti find a solution but failed. 
Please tell me where I went wrong in my code. A solution for this bug will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: explain what you mean by *find condition fails*. Is it no records or an error? also how are you verifying it?

Comment: Consider I want to find records in the name 'SARA' from mongoDB. If the condition matches it should return 'record found' or else 'No record found'. "{DOC_NAME : criteria.DOC_NAME}" this part is the condition in the code.

Comment: so you say it goes to else block when no record is found. so just put a `console.log(er,users);` in the found block to check what exactly was in them

Comment: when the condition fails I have empty array block [] for variable 'users'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your condition like

```
if( err){
   console.log("An error occurred");
} else if(!users || users.length==0) {
   console.log("No results found");
} else {
   console.log('record found');
}
```

You need to add a condition to check if the returned array was empty.

#### note :

[**javascript empty array seems to be true and false at the same time**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491605/javascript-empty-array-seems-to-be-true-and-false-at-the-same-time) gives a proper explanation on why u should not use `if(!users)` to check if the array was empty.

Comment: yeah checking for array length is good option. But as far as the examples I have seen they used only the if(!users) condition. Why it is not working? any explanation would be helpful.

Comment: sorry, I don't get anything.

Comment: when you do `if(arr)` it returns true if the object is present. In your case arr is present. But if you checked whether arr evaluates to false, then it will return you true as `[]==""` is true. Need more clarification? You can also read the link i updated in my answer.

Comment: got it, thanks for the help. Have you ever came across this situation. The reason I keep on asking is that I have seen lot of examples using it.

Comment: I have come across but I got more clarity from the [above answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491605/javascript-empty-array-seems-to-be-true-and-false-at-the-same-time) I mentioned on SO. How I approached it earlier was to check if the array was instanceOf array and then try to check its length == 0. :)