# why does "[] == 0" return true while "[]" is true and "0" is false?

Tags: javascript

If i execute the following lines in thw browser console

```
!![] //--- returns true
!!0 //--- returns false
```

I get that `[]` and `0` have different boolean values.

I don't understand why

```
[] == 0 //--- returns true
```

returns `true`.

What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing `===` an `=` in equality operator

Comment: So many duplicates.. tldr; there are different conversions that occur. `!` applies [ToBoolean] [*while `==` uses different conversions*](https://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3) ([ToNumber], [ToPrimitive]) depending on the type of both operands.

Comment: The `!` operator always converts to boolean, but `==` does other conversions to turn the data into values that are possible to compare.

Comment: `[]` and `0` are both falsey  values so both are equal to each other

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615214/in-javascript-why-is-0-equal-to-false-but-when-tested-by-if-it-is-not-fals?lq=1

Comment: @hitesh1124 That is not correct. As a counter example, `false == null` is *not* true.

Comment: For more clarifications check this out! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491605/empty-arrays-seem-to-equal-true-and-false-at-the-same-time

Comment: just to do your head in a little more ... `[x] == x` but `[x] != [x]` :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Not universally true. As a counter example, `[undefined] == undefined` is *not* true.

Comment: ok, where x is a number, or a string at least

Comment: you may want to read this http://stackoverflow.com/q/7202157/995714

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that array is object and 0 is number.

And as "user2864740" told..

1) When you doing

```
!![] //--- returns true
!!0 //--- returns false
```

You are performing so called **"ToBoolean"** convertion

https://es5.github.io/#x9.2

Number

> The result is false if the argument is +0, −0, or NaN; otherwise the
>   result is true.

Object ( our [] )

> always true

2) But when you using == you performing so called **"Equality Comparison"**

https://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3

Here thins a little bit complicated but to understand what happens you have to remember that == do a type coercion ( so you can compare oranges to apples :) )

First of all compiler converts [] to some primitive type.

> If Type(x) is either String or Number and Type(y) is Object, return
>   the result of the comparison x == ToPrimitive(y).

How ToPrimitive works is a matter of an article :), but's it easy to remember that closet primitive type to array is string. Array will be converted to empty string.

[].toString() === ""

So now we need to compare empty string and number 0

```
"" == 0   // true
```

Hmmm. So it's true. But why is that? Remember that when you compare with **"Equality Comparison"** number and string

> 4. If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).

So let's try to convert empty string to number

```
Number("") === 0
```

And in the end

```
0 === 0
```

I hope that's explains something :)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is probably converting the array to a number:
`!!Number([])    // false`
`Number([]) == 0 // true`

Comment: is that because the left side is converted to the type of the right side ??

Comment: well, you can't really convert 0 to an array

Comment: he convert array to int it returns 0