# Interesting array with null elements JavaScript behavior

Tags: javascript

I found some interesting behavior and I'm wondering why it's the case.

```
var test = [null] // array with a single null element

> test == true
false

> test == false
true

> if(test) {console.log('true');}
'true'
```

Here's where it gets more interesting.

```
var test = [null, null]

> test == true
false

> test == false
false

> if(test) {console.log('true');}
'true'
```

Any idea why it behaves like this?

Comment: Comparing an array to a non-array with `==` has little practical use unless you consider this entertainment or you enjoy studying intricacies of type conversion rules in the ECMAScript spec.  What is the point of this?

Comment: That has been asked a few times. Search for truthy and falsy. `if (something not null, empty string, 0)` will always return true. As for the others, look at what the test.toString() returns and you will see why [null]==false is true and [null,null]==false is false

Comment: no wait we are doing some mess, now i read better, he try to compare a boolean to anything else, it's clearly alway false, and the condition give true everytime it didn't have '==' operator unless is undefined.

Comment: If you really want to know the answer to this, then go study type conversion rules in the ECMAScript specification.  The answer is all there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `==` is used to compare things of different types, like an array (`[null]`) and `false`, it has specific steps it goes through, called the [Abstract Equality Algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-abstract-equality-comparison) (quoted below) to try to coerce them to things that it can compare. (Because `==` is the "loose" equality operator.)

First it sees if either operand is `null` or `undefined`, but in this case neither is.

Then it sees if it's comparing a number and a string, but that's not true in this case either.

Then it seems if either operand is a boolean, which of course on of these is. Since one of them is a boolean, it does an abstract operation called [`ToNumber`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-tonumber) in the spec to convert the other one to a number and does another `==`. (The `Number` function, when used as a function and not a constructor, is basically a wrapper for that abstract `ToNumber` operation.)

So

```
[null] == false
```

becomes

```
0 == false
```

...because `ToNumber([null])` coerces its argument to a string (via [`ToPrimitive`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-toprimitive)), getting `""`, and then converts that to `0`.

So now `==` has something where one of the operands is a number. SO it converts the *other* one to a number as well. `Number(false)` is `0`.

Thus, `[null] == false` is true.

---

So what about `[null, null] == false`? When converting `[null, null]` to a string, we get `","`, which `ToNumber` can't turn into a valid number. So it converts it to `NaN`. One of the fun things about `NaN` is that it's a number, but it's never equal to anything else. So:

```
[null, null] == false
```

becomes

```
NaN == false
```

becomes

```
NaN == 0
```

...which is `false`, because (again) `NaN` is never equal to anything.

---

Here's that Abstract Equality Algorithm:

1. [ReturnIfAbrupt](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-returnifabrupt)(`x`).
2. [ReturnIfAbrupt](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-returnifabrupt)(`y`).
3. If [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(`x`) is the same as Type(`y`), then

   a) Return the result of performing Strict Equality Comparison `x` === `y`.
4. If `x` is `null` and `y` is `undefined`, return `true`.
5. If `x` is `undefined` and `y` is `null`, return `true`.
6. If [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(`x`) is Number and Type(`y`) is String,
   return the result of the comparison
   `x` == [ToNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-tonumber)(`y`).
7. If [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(`x`) is String and Type(`y`) is Number,
   return the result of the comparison ToNumber(`x`) == `y`.
8. If [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(`x`) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison
   [ToNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-tonumber)(`x`) == `y`.
9. If [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(`y`) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison
   `x` == [ToNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-tonumber)(`y`).
10. If [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(`x`) is either String, Number, or Symbol and Type(`y`) is Object, then
    return the result of the comparison
    `x` == [ToPrimitive](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-toprimitive)(`y`).
11. If [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(`x`) is Object and Type(`y`) is either String, Number, or Symbol, then
    return
    the result of the comparison [ToPrimitive](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-toprimitive)(`x`) == `y`.
12. Return `false`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491605/empty-arrays-seem-to-equal-true-and-false-at-the-same-time
This is a good reference on JS == comparisons, specifically with arrays