# Null checking in Javascript (with ternary operator)

Tags: javascript, performance

want to check null values. `any()` method returns `null` or array of matched result (actually there's a `match()` method inside which is returned).

```
$scope.isMobileBrowser = !isMobile.any() ? false : true;
```

If `any()` method returns null I want `false` to be assigned to `$scope.isMobileBrowser` variable, otherwise `true`. will the over mentioned snippet fail in any probable case? Is there any other more efficient workaround?

for more details of `isMobile` object:

```
var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    Opera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
    }
};
```

Comment: *Is there any other more efficient workaround?* - Are you sure that your program is slow just because of this line?

Comment: No, it's not slow. I would like to know the correctness, also if there exists any other better options.

Comment: If you really don't need the returned array, use `test()` instead of `match()`.

Comment: `String.match` **does not** return a string. It returns `null` or `Array`.

Comment: Please add the `any` method as well too check what values will be returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Empty string is also a falsy value.
If `any()` returns an empty string, `!isMobile.any() ? false : true` will return `false`, but you probably want `true`.

This means your code is incorrect for this case.

I'd just do something like `isMobile.any() !== null`.

Comment: Why would `any` return an empty string? As @Salman commented in the original Question?

Comment: @sabithpocker The OP states *`any()` method returns `null` or `string`*. That's the only thing for sure. The additional *"actually there's a `match()` method inside which is returned"* suggests some implementation details, but quite vague. @Salman's also suggests that there's more going on there.
So with the question as it is formulated now, we have `null` or `string` returned and there's nothing prohibiting this string to be empty.

Answer (score 1):

As per the `any()` function, you are returning value of the following expression:

```
(isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() 
                             || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows())
```

Each of these functions can either return an `Array` or `null` as seen in the [doc for match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

So while evaluating the `OR` it will ***evaluate to*** the first `truth` value encountered and doesnt evaluate any further as the expression is already fit to be true. So, for example if the browser is android the expression evaluates to `["Android"]`. If windows it will be `["Windows"]`. If none of these, it will be `null`. Which makes it clear that `any()` can only return an `Array` or `null`.

`isMobileBrowser` should be `true` if it's any of these mobile browsers, which means `isMobileBrowser` should be `true` if:

`any()` evaluates to an `Array`

*OR in other way*:

If `any()` does not evaluate to `null`

which is:

```
$scope.isMobileBrowser = isMobile.any() instanceof Array;//looks messy
$scope.isMobileBrowser = (isMobile.any()).constructor === Array;//looks messy
$scope.isMobileBrowser = Array.isArray(isMobile.any());//looks messy
$scope.isMobileBrowser = Object.prototype.toString.call(isMobile.any()) 
                                   === "[object Array]";//looks messy
```

OR the other way:

```
$scope.isMobileBrowser = isMobile.any() !== null;
$scope.isMobileBrowser = !(isMobile.any() === null);
isMobileBrowser = !(Object.prototype.toString.call(isMobile.any()) 
                                   === "[object Null]");//looks messy
```

So we just discussed different ways to check for `null` and `Array`. You have two possible sets of outputs

1. `null` value which is always `false`
2. An `Array` which is always `true` (You can check this [empty array scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491605/empty-arrays-seem-to-equal-true-and-false-at-the-same-time) although that doesn't apply here)

So you can simply do the following to **convert** those to exact `boolean` without worrying much:

```
isMobileBrowser = Boolean(isMobile.any()); //to convert value to boolean
isMobileBrowser = !!isMobile.any(); //another way to convert to boolean
                                   //!!["Android"] is true
                                   //!!null is false
```

@rossipedia explains the `!!` well in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

A compact way of representing what you want would be:

```
$scope.isMobileBrowser = !!isMobile.any();
```

The `!!` there does two things:

1. The first `!` evaluates the "truthiness"<sup>1</sup> of the return value of `isMobile.any()` and then negates it.
2. The second `!` negates that value again.

So what you end up with is `false` if `.any()` returns `null`, otherwise `true`.

However, this may fail in edge cases where `.any()` returns something that is "falsy". In that case, checking for `null` specifically is what you want:

```
isMobile.any() !== null
```

<sup>1</sup>: "Truthiness":

> In JavaScript, a truthy value is a value that translates to true when evaluated in a Boolean context. All values are truthy unless they are defined as falsy (i.e., except for false, 0, "", null, undefined, and NaN).

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)

Comment: `!!isMobile.any()` will be `false` if `any()` returns `""`. Should be true according to the question.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

`$scope.isMobileBrowser = isMobile.any() === null;`

Comment: I think `===` is wrong: *If `any()` method returns `null` I want `false` to be assigned to `$scope.isMobileBrowser` variable...*

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.