# Empty array is falsy, yet [] ? 0 : 1 evaluates to 0

Tags: javascript, arrays

If the empty array `[]` is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) in JavaScript then why, when used as the predicate in the ternary operator, the operator evals to the first option?

```
console.log([] == false); // prints true
console.log([] ? 0 : 1);  // prints 0 !
```

Comment: did you have a look at `console.log([]===false);`?

Comment: Try `[]===false` and check.

Comment: Note that `[]===false` is false but `[]==false` is true, my guess is that is comes down to how javascript assesses `[]`'s type

Comment: By the way, `!![]` is true, and that's probably what happens when you use it like this in a ternary or an `if` statement. `if([]) console.log(0)` prints `0` as well.

Comment: You're assuming that `if ([]) { }` is equivalent to `if ([] == true) { }` which is not the case in JS since `==` has a non trivial behaviour when comparing two operands which are not of the same type (check the docs and the post by ojovirtual).

Comment: @lucas `[]===false` is `false`; this is not surprising.

Comment: The answer can be found at the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491605/empty-arrays-seem-to-equal-true-and-false-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

An array is not falsy; this can be demonstrated using `console.log(!![])`

When doing a left vs. right comparison via the `==` operand JavaScript attempts to coerce the inputs to a common type.

With your first example of `[] == false`, the following occurs:

1. The right-hand side is found to be `Boolean` so it is converted to a `Number` value, resulting in the comparison being `[] == 0`.
2. Since the left-hand side is an `Object` it is converted to a primitive; in this case a `String` via `[].toString()`, resulting in the comparison being `"" == 0`.
3. Since the left-hand side is a `String`, it gets converted to a `number` value resulting in `0 == 0`.
4. Since both sides are `Number` primitives, their values are compared, resulting in a truthy condition

With the second example of `[] ? 0 : 1`, there is no right-hand value to compare to, so it simply tests if the input is truthy. The array is not `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `""` or `NaN`, so it is treated as truthy and thus the 'true' option is returned: `0`;

To force a non-coercive comparison between two inputs you should use the `===` operand.

[Ecma Standard 6th edition Entry on Coercion](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-abstract-equality-comparison)
[JS Coercion Explained](http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2010/10/javascript-coercion-demystified.html)

Comment: Dear JS, I don't like this :(
So much under-the-hood coercion to bite me in the ass

Comment: For anyone who complains that this is not intuitive: what are you doing comparing arrays with booleans in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

Just to remember.

Javascript has two types of comparison operators:

1. Strict `===`: Checks the type as well as the value
2. Type Converting: `==` Checks only the value.

Try these and check the results:

`console.log([] === false); //prints false
     console.log([] == false); //prints true
     console.log(0 == false);  //prints true
     console.log(1 == "1")  // prints true
     console.log(1 === "1") //prints false`

I hope It helps.

Comment: This does not explain the reason behind what is happening, it simply shows examples of `==` vs `===`

Answer (score 2):

adding on the above answers..

to get the true boolean value of any value you can prefix it with `!!`(in this way you won't run in any coercion issues);

in your case you can do this:

```
console.log(!![] == false)   //logs false
```