# If [] is falsy, how come ![] is also falsy

Tags: javascript

We know that in JS `[] == false` returns `true`. But today I was watching a video presentation by Kyle Simpson and I saw this:

```
[] == ![]   // true
```

How come `![]` is also falsy. As per my logic, it should be `true`.

Comment: `[]` isn't falsey...

Comment: Then why `[] == false` is true? What have I missed.

Comment: @RajatSaxena Because `[]` is coerced to `""`, then to `0`, while `false` is coerced to `0`, and `0 === 0` is `true`. Abstract comparison with `false` does _not_ tell you whether something is falsy. `!![]` does.

Comment: Oh! It seems like I've learnt the concept from some bad sources. Anyway, I also found this explanation in-depth: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33567406/942589

Comment: @SebastianSimon Can you please put your comment as an answer. I will accept.

Comment: @RajatSaxena It seems as though my comment is covered by the answer you linked and its linked questions.

Answer (score 0):

== allows coercion. So does ! operator. So [] == ![] becomes "" == false which is true. Further ![] is true because [] is an object which is a true value. And negation of that yields false.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, not operator (`!`) check for not condition like this `!(true)`, here first it checks the inner part of `()`, If it returns `true` then the actual output becomes `false`. 
 `(true)` => `!(true) =>`false
(false)`=>`!(false)`=>`true`

Get back to original question
`[]` return `true` where as `![]` return `false` when you compare strictly with `===` its check for `type` and `value` both.

```js
 console.log([]); // true
 console.log(![]); // false
 console.log([] == ![]) // true
 console.log([] ===![]) // false
```

> **Note** if you want `boolean` value all the time then you can use `!!`.

```js
 console.log(!![]); // true
 console.log(!!(1 === 1)); // true
```