# Javascript: comparison logs true in these two exceptions

Tags: javascript

Why in Javascript only for these values, the result is true:
I know that the == operator sets to boolean behind the scenes, but how this only works with the array literal and 0 as string?.

```
1) [] == ![] //logs true
2) "0" == !"0" //logs true
```

Thanks

Comment: Who really cares? If you're writing code like this, you have bigger problems...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Empty arrays seem to equal true and false at the same time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491605/empty-arrays-seem-to-equal-true-and-false-at-the-same-time)

Comment: Is not for coding at all, is a question my friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases, `![]` and `!"0"` are boolean `false`.

Type shifting then goes...

`[]` => `0` => `false`
`"0"` => `0` => `false`

Result: `false == false`, which is true.