# Returning of empty array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I noticed this behaviour in JS:

```
alert (new Array() == false); // true
```

Can someone explain - why? I don't even know how to google it.

**edit**

you are trying to say, that `new array() == []`,
but why:

```
var someVar = []; 
alert (someVar == false); // true
```

I don't see it

Comment: *"why?"* **Type conversion**: `[] => "" => 0`. `false => 0`. `0 == 0`

Comment: @FelixKling then why `[] && true` is `true`

Comment: @JasmineOT: different kind of type conversion. `&&` converts its operands to Boolean values. Every object is truthy, i.e. `Boolean([])` returns `true`. **Comparing** a value to a Boolean is very different than **converting** it to a Boolean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `==` will cause `toString()` on the newly created object to be called and it will return `""` and through coercion it will equal `false`.

always use `===`.

Comment: This answer is correct; however it doesn't clarify why the `.toString` method returns an empty string in this case.

Comment: i updated, can you explain why? i am not creating new objects

Comment: @alexey check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491605/empty-arrays-seem-to-equal-true-and-false-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 1):

The above problem has to do with the .ToString() method being called on the newly created object which returns "" which is False in Javascript.

Comment: You should remove the incorrect part of your answer.

Comment: @FelixKling I wasn't sure if I was supposed too or not, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `new Array()`  returns `[]` which means empty array.A empty array is  evaluted as `false`

S,thats why  `new Array() === false //true`
this can be written as

```
[].toString()==false //true
```

[toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) method join the array element and return string with comman separated.Howevever,there is no single element in `[]` which is empty
`[].join()` will return `""` which is why `[].toString return ""`

`[].toString()` can be written as  `[].join()`

Comment: *"A empty array is evaluted as false"* No! `Boolean([])` is `true`.

Comment: You are doing typecasting using wrapper.I am talkiing [] and not Boolean([])

Comment: This is just to demonstrate that an empty is not "evaluated as`false`". What else do you mean by that expression if not casting the array to a Boolean value?

Comment: so,what about this        ` []==false `?

Comment: What happens here is that both, the array and `false` are converted to numbers, and they happen to be both converted to `0`. `[0] == false` and `['00000'] == false` are `true` as well. The important point here is that the array **is not** converted to a Boolean.

Comment: ok.Thanks@FelixKling  thats new for me