# Explain why '+[] == 0' output 'true' in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Explain why `+[] == 0` give output **'true'** in Javascript?

Please, check example.

```js
+[] == 0 ? alert(true) : alert(false);
```

And also check.
`'1+[+[]]'` give output **'10'**

Comment: have a look here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5491730/1377002

Answer (score 9):

It will be evaluated like below,

**1 :** `+[] == 0` --> `+"" == 0`

*Operator `+` is having [highest priority](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than `==` so it will be evaluated first. So during the conversion of an array to number, [`ToPrimitive()`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1) function will be called by passing it as an argument. Since `[]` is an `object`,  it will return `""` string*

**2 :** `+"" == 0` --> `0 == 0`

*An empty string will be converted to `0`. And a non-empty string would be converted to `NaN` as we all know.*

**3 :**  `0 == 0` --> `true`

*And finally as per [abstract equality comparison algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3), when both operands of same type getting compared, no further evaluation will happen, it will directly checks for its equality and return the result.*

---

And in your second case `1+[+[]]`, evaluation will happen like,

**1 :** `1+[+[]]` - ( *`+[]` will be converted to primitive first since `[]` it is an object*)

**2 :** `1+[+""]` ( *[`toPrimitive([])`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1) will be `""`* )

**3 :** `1+[0]` ( *`0` will be yielded when you convert an empty string to number* )

**4 :** `1+"0"` ( *[`toPrimitive([0])`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1) will be `"0"`* )

**5 :** `"10"`

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript evaluates `+[] == 0` this way:

1. `+ []`: `+` operator tries to convert the operand `[]` to a primitive value.
2. `+ []`: `[]` is transformed to a string using `toString()` method, which is an alias for `[].join(',')`. The result is an empty string `''`
3. `+ ''`: the empty string is transformed to a number: `Number('')`-> `0`
4. `+ 0` becomes `0`
5. Finally the comparison is evaluated: `+[] == 0` -> `0 == 0` -> `true`

The `'1+[+[]]'` evaluation:

1. `1 + [ +[] ]` (Transform `[]` into a primitive: `''`)
2. `1 + [ + '' ]` (Transform `''` into a number: `0`)
3. `1 + [ + 0 ]` (`+ 0` is `0`)
4. `1 + [ 0 ]` (Addition operator forces the transform of `[0]` into a primitive value: `[0].toString()` -> `[0].join(',')` -> `'0'`)
5. `1 + '0'` (Because the second operand `'0'` is a string, transform the first number `1` to a string too: `'1'`)
6. `'1' + '0'` (Simple strings concatenation)
7. `'10'`

Read also [this article](http://rainsoft.io/javascriptss-addition-operator-demystified/) about the addition operator.