# Using operators as variables gives odd results

Tags: javascript

```
! + [] === true
```

Can someone explain what's happening here?  I understand this is not normal, but I'm struggling to understand what the compiler is doing when it seems operators used in place of variables in mathematical operations.

more examples of this strangeness:

```
(! + '') === (!'')
```

but

```
(! + []) !== (![])
```

Comment: Read it like this: `!(+[])`. I suggest you just add all the examples to https://astexplorer.net/, and see what operators are being used in what order.

Comment: What's _not_ happening here is operators being used as variables. Things like `[]` and `{}` are *values* in any expression context, just like `3` and `true` are. The operators like `===`, `!`, etc are being used as operators.

Comment: @ASDFGerte 's comment made it make sense to me. I should read it as (+[]) which coerces an object -> string -> number.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript always convert inputs to Primitive types. So in your case of `! + []` it will try to convert `+[]` to string. which will be `""` and then because of `!` it will convert into `boolean`. in JavaScript `""` is consider as `false`. So ultimately it will return `!false` which will be `true`.

**Edit 1**

As @mhodges has commented below. `[]` getting convert to string as `""` then `+` will convert it to `number`, so it will become `0`.

You can learn more about object to primitive from here.
[object to primitive](https://javascript.info/object-toprimitive)

You can check behavior below.

```js
var emptyBrackets = [].toString();
// conversion to string.
console.log(emptyBrackets === '');
// conversion to number.
console.log(+emptyBrackets);
// conversion to boolean.
console.log(!0);
```

Comment: Isn't the `+` being used to convert to a number here? `+"" === 0`, then `!0 === true`

Comment: @Keatinge I think you're partially correct. I think Karan is right in that [] is converted to `""` before being coerced to a number by `+` as you said.

Comment: The **very** important missing piece to this answer is that the `+` is being used to coerce `""` into a number (`0`). Saying that "it will try to convert `+[]` to a string" is just flat wrong.

Comment: @mhodges all the coercions that are being talked about here are happening because of `+`, but yes, internally, it will be coerced to string before being again coerced to number. The text implies that `+[] === ""` though, which is simply wrong (apart from several other not-so-well-formumated parts, see "JavaScript always convert inputs to Primitive types" - what?). I don't understand why this even gets upvoted.

Comment: @mhodges. Thanks for drawing my attention about `+`. I have updated answer accordingly.

Comment: @Karan Close, still not entirely accurate. There is no such thing as an `int` in JavaScript - it's a `Number` type. Coercing the array (via `+`) will call `.toPrimitive()` on the empty array internally, which converts it to its [default value](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.8) (an empty string), before coercing it to a Number with `+`. It's a matter of semantics, but with questions like this, semantics are extremely important

Comment: The part about `+[] => 0` is explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101362/explain-why-0-output-true-in-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

First, it is important to know what operators are being used, and in what order. When this is not clear, an easy way to find out is to look at what the syntax parser makes out of it, e.g. using https://astexplorer.net/, which shows for the first example that:

`! + [] === true` uses unary logical not (`!`), unary plus (`+`), an array literal which is empty (`[]`), strict equality (`===`) and the keyword for true (`true`).

Execution order is `(!(+[])) === true`, or seen as a tree:

```
   ===
 /     \
!     true
|
+
|
[]
```

---

What follows is to understand, what each of the operators are transforming their operands to. This is a bit tedious, when you want to know in detail.

I assume you know what an empty array literal or `true` produce. Strict equality `===` is likely also known, as it does not have very many unintuitive aspects (contrary to loose equality `==`, which has a LOT). Relevant are therefore only the steps of the unary + and unary logical not.

Given the order of operations, we first look at [unary +](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-unary-plus-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation) with `[]` as operand. It performs [`ToNumber`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-tonumber) on the operand, which, for objects like our example `[]`, performs `ToPrimitive` followed by another `ToNumber`. `ToPrimitive` will try `valueOf` (which will not return a primitive and is therefore not taken), followed by `toString`. The latter, for arrays, searches for the function `join` and calls it without arguments (setting the array as `this`). For an empty array, this results in the empty string `""`, which will be converted to `0` by the following second call of `ToNumber`.

Next is the [unary logical not](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-logical-not-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation), which first transforms any operand with [`ToBoolean`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-toboolean). This intermediary step results in `false` for our operand `0`. Then, as expected, the opposite is being returned (`true`).

Last but least, as we know, `true === true` evaluates to `true`.

An interesting sidenote here is the use of `Array.prototype.join` in the default case. I would expect many to be surprised, why changes to `join` would affect the outcome:

```
console.log(! + [] === true);

let x = [];
x.join = () => "1";
console.log(! + x === true);

Array.prototype.join = () => "1";
console.log(! + [] === true);
```

---

The other examples work in a similar way:

- `(! + '')` is almost the same, just that `ToNumber` does not even need the prior `ToPrimitive`
- For `(!'')`, `ToBoolean` of an empty string is `false`, therefore resulting in `true`
- For `(![])`, `ToBoolean` of any object is `true`, resulting in `false`