# Why Array is equal not array (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean, comparison, boolean-logic

We all know that JavaScript is quite a funny language with tricky parts.
Please, explain how it works, if possible: `[ ]` is equal `![ ]` .

```
 [ ] == ![ ]    // -> true
```

I don't understand it, why the result is `"true"`?

Comment: Because array in JavaScript is an object. [See Mozilla CDN Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `==` doesn't compare them typesafe, but the values get casted:

```
[] == ![]
//is
[] == false
//is casted into
"" == false
//and that into
false == false
//wich is
true
```

use the typesafe comparison

```js
console.log(`[] == ![]`, [] == ![])
console.log(`[] === ![]`, [] === ![])
```

in my opinion, the only reason to use `==` is when you chack against `null` or `undefined` and want to cover both. So, writing

```
value == null
//or
value != null

//instead of the more explicit (but longer)
value === null || value === undefined
//respectively
value !== null && value !== undefined
```

everywhere else I'd use `===` because of these funny results that `==` sometimes has.

Here's a funny little clip on that topic, enjoy: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Comment: Thomas, thanks for answers. I review some crazy examples and try to understand how they work. Now I understand this example.

Comment: @YuriiSavchuk for more info, research into truthy and falsy values.

Answer (score 0):

When you call if (array == false) you compare values of this object and the primitive false value. Internally, arr.toString() is called, which returns an empty string "".

```
![] // will return false

[] == false // this would return true, since "" == false
```

```js
console.log((![]).toString());
console.log(([]).toString());
console.log("" == false);
```

This is how it is called internally, please check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491605/empty-arrays-seem-to-equal-true-and-false-at-the-same-time)
 for more details

Comment: marvel308, thanks for answers. I review some crazy examples and try to understand how they work. Now I understand this example.