# [[]] == false. Why?

Tags: javascript

A bug just threw me for a good 45 minute loop scratching my head, when finally I realized assigning an array containing another (empty) array `myArray = [[]]`, holds equivalence with `false`:

```
if (myArray == false) {} // true
```

I realize that `if (myArray === false) {} // false` but why would an array with length > 0 have equivalence to `false` at all?

Comment: I think you are confused somehow, empty array, and array with elements evaluate to `true`

Comment: @thedude - They're not confused, the result of `[[]] == false` is indeed `true`.

Comment: When you invoke the (myArray == false) you compare values of that myArray object (array is instance of object in javascript) and then myArray.toString() is called, which returns an empty string "". This is because toString called on Array returns Array.join(), and empty string is one of falsy values in JavaScript.

Comment: That’s why it’s wise to avoid `==` at all time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Empty arrays seem to equal true and false at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491605/empty-arrays-seem-to-equal-true-and-false-at-the-same-time)

Comment: @FaristaLatuconsina - **Thank you**, I was going nuts looking for it. Viziionary - You may also be interested in [these bizarre-seeming behaviors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder woah another interesting discussion bout javascript behaviour which in case i haven't seen it, thank you.

Comment: Thank you all for the info and answers and these related questions/answers, all super interesting stuff.

Answer (score 6):

It's because `==` recursively converts its operands into things it can compare until their types are the same, via the [Abstract Equality Comparison](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison) operation:

- In `x == y`, since `y` is boolean, it does the result of `x == ToNumber(y)` ([`ToNumber`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tonumber)).
- `ToNumber(false)` is `0`, so it does `x == 0`.
- Since `x` is an object and `0` is a number, it does `ToPrimitive(x) == 0`. ([`ToPrimitive`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-toprimitive).)
- `ToPrimitive([[]])` is `""` because it ends up doing a `join` on the array (via `Array.prototype.toString`), converting the operands to strings. So now we have `"" == 0`.
- The algorithm does `ToNumber("") == 0`. `ToNumber("")` is `0`, so we end up with `0 == 0` which is true.

*(When looking at the algorithm in the spec, don't be thrown by the `!` in front of some operations like `ToNumber`. It does **not** mean negation like it would in JavaScript. It means the operation will never return an abrupt completion. [This guide](https://timothygu.me/es-howto/) to reading the spec helps with things like that.)*

Answer (score 2):

When you call `[[]] == false`, you compare values of the array and primitive boolean value. So `toString()` method is called.
`[[]].toString() is equal to ''` so you will compare `'' == false` and it's true.