# Javascript apparent madness

Tags: javascript, language-design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conflicting boolean values of an empty JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226101/conflicting-boolean-values-of-an-empty-javascript-array)

What is the rationale behind the fact that

```
[ ([] == false), ([] ? 1 : 2) ]
```

returns `[true, 1]`?

In other words an empty list is logically true in a boolean context, but is equal to `false`.

I know that using `===` solves the issue, but what is the explanation behind this apparently totally illogical choice?

In other words is this considered a mistake in the language, something unintentional that just happened and that cannot be fixed because it's too late or really in the design of the language someone thought it was cool to have this kind of apparent madness that I'm sure is quite confusing for many programmers?

The technical explanation of how this happens is at the same time amazing and scaring, I was however more interested in what is behind this design.

### Edit

I accepted very detailed Nick Retallack explanation, even if it's only about the technical reasons of why `[]==false` is true: surprisingly enough it happens is because `[]` converted to string is an empty string and the empty string numeric value is special cased to be 0 instead of the apparently more logical `NaN`. With an empty object for example the comparison `({}) == false` returns false because the string representation of an empty object is not the empty string.

My curiosity still remains about all this being just unanticipated (and now unfortunately solidified in a standard).

Comment: that's fun! [].toString() problem maybe?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491605/javascript-empty-array-seems-to-be-true-and-false-at-the-same-time

Comment: http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/966449#r15310322

Comment: `![] == false` returns `true` too. :-)

Comment: @ElliotBonneville another funny thing: `![].toString() == false` returns `false`.

Comment: @BenniKa, that's because `[].toString() == false` is `true`. Doh. :p

Comment: @ElliotBonneville i know, my comment wasn't meant serious xD. (My english sounds terrible oO )

Comment: @BenniKa: Heh, so was mine, hence the "Doh". I would never say that seriously. And hey, don't worry about your English. I understand what you're saying, so no worries. XD

Comment: In any complex language you should be able to say things which appear counterintuitive. Usually this isn't a problem though because people avoid those situations automatically. To keep things simple there needs to be an easily predictable result rather than an intuitive result for all possible expressions. So when you're constructing a language you try to have as few rules as possible, starting with something that makes sense to you. For example when comparing a mix of string/boolean/number you coerce them to numbers. An empty string should equal `false`, so both `""` and `false` become `0`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's get technical.  I'll explain the logic with quotes from the [ECMAScript Standard 262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf).

The expression `[] ? 1 : 2` is very simple:

> **11.12 Conditional Operator ( ? : )**
>
> - Let lref be the result of evaluating LogicalORExpression.
> - If **ToBoolean(GetValue(lref))** is true, then
>
>   - Let trueRef be the result of evaluating the first AssignmentExpression.
>   - Return GetValue(trueRef).
> - Else
>
>   - Let falseRef be the result of evaluating the second AssignmentExpression.
>   - Return GetValue(falseRef)
>
> **9.2 ToBoolean**
>
> - Undefined: false
> - Null: false
> - Boolean: The result equals the input argument (no conversion).
> - Number: The result is false if the argument is +0, 0, or NaN; otherwise the result is  true.
> - String: The result is false if the
>     argument is the empty String (its length is zero); otherwise the
>     result is true.
> - **Object: true**

So it's true.

---

Now for the wild ride of what happens when you use the double equals operator.  Perhaps this will help explain why you should never do this.

The behavior of == is explained in  in section 11.9.3: The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm.

For x == y where x = [] and y = false, this happens:

> **11.9.3: The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm**
>
> If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y)
>
> **9.3 ToNumber**
>
> The result is **+0** if the argument is 
>   **false**.

Now we have [] == 0

> **11.9.3: The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm**
>
> If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String or Number, return
>   the result of the comparison **ToPrimitive(x) == y**.
>
> **9.1 ToPrimitive**
>
> Return a default value for the Object. The default value of an object
>   is  retrieved by calling the **[[DefaultValue]]**  internal  method of the
>   object,  passing the optional hint  PreferredType. The behaviour of
>   the  [[DefaultValue]] internal method is defined by this specification
>   for all native  ECMAScript objects in 8.12.8.
>
> **8.12.8 DefaultValue:**
>
> When the [[DefaultValue]] internal method of  O is called with no
>   hint, then it behaves as if the hint were **Number**
>
> - Let valueOf be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of object O with argument "valueOf".
> - If IsCallable(valueOf) is true then,
>
>   - Let val be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method of valueOf, with O as the this value and  an empty argument list.
>   - If val is a primitive value, return val
> - Let toString be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of object O with argument "toString".
> - If IsCallable(toString) is true then,
>
>   - Let str be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method of **toString**, with O as the this value and  an empty argument list.
>   - If str is a primitive value, **return str**.

I assume this first attempts valueOf and then rejects it because the result is the same array you started with.  It then calls toString on Array, which seems to be universally implemented as a comma separated list of its values.  For empty arrays like this one, that results in empty string.

Now we have '' == 0

> **11.9.3: The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm**
>
> If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number, return the result of the
>   comparison **ToNumber(x) == y**
>
> **9.3.1 ToNumber Applied to the String Type**
>
> A StringNumericLiteral that is **empty or contains only white space** is
>   converted to **+0**.

Now we have 0 == 0

> **11.9.3: The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm**
>
> If x is the same Number value as y, return true

Awesome.  It's true.  Pretty convoluted way of getting here though.

Comment: So someone read the link in my comment :D .

Comment: This is a spectacular answer.

Comment: @NickRetallack you edited your answer quite often, in the beginning it was much like the link http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/966449#r15310322 in my comment. Of course your answer is now much more detailed.

Answer (score 9):

The confusion here is around the definition of "falsy" in JavaScript, which (contrary to popular belief) isn't the same as `== false`.

Falsy actually refers to a value that has a boolean equivalent of false, not an expression whose result == false. The only Falsy values in JavaScript are: `false`, `0`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, and `NaN`. So any of those values -- or any expression that evalutes to one of those values (like in an `if` statment or using the ternary operator) -- is falsy.

Here's a table I put together of falsy/truthy values in JavaScript that should help explain this whole issue.
http://jsfiddle.net/philipwalton/QjSYG/

Comment: Great table! It's worth noting, however, that the confusion here appears to be from the fact that `[] == false` evaluates to false because it's the same as `[].toString() == false`, so ultimately it's `'' == false`.

Comment: @jmar777 are you sure? If I run `[] === ""` in the console I get false, so how can `[]` be the same as `[].toString()`. Can you cite something showing that `[] == false` is equivalent to `[].toString == false`

Comment: @Philip the difference is in the `===` vs. `==`. When you just use the double-equals, type coercion is allowed. What technically happens (with `==`) is the JavaScript engine says "is `[]` equal to `''`?". The answer is obviously no, so it says "well, let me try with some type coercion...". The question is now "is `''` equal to `''`?", which is now true. When you use the `===` operator however, that second step never occurs, hence it evaluates to false.

Comment: You can read up on how this works here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators.  Specifically, "... if either operand is a string, the other operand is converted to a string if possible."

Comment: @jmar777, I understand the difference between `==` and `===`, I was mainly looking for evidence of the fact that the JavaScript interpreter actually calls `toString` on `[]`. It looks like here is an explanation of what is going on under the hood: http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.9.3

Comment: @PhilipWalton Check my answer.  It shows where in the spec it says this.

Comment: @PhilipWalton Right - if you didn't check out the mozilla link I posted, it it explains it there.

Comment: Doh, somehow I had a mental derailment there, and was thinking that your starting expression was `[] == ''`. My comment would be valid in that scenario, but given that it was really `[] == false`, @NickRetallack answer is an absolutely outstanding breakdown of what's going on.

Comment: @NickRetallack yes, I was working through that spec myself as you were updating your answer. It's quite involved :)