# Student trying to understand callback functions

Tags: javascript, callback

Hi I'm trying to learn how to implement callback functions.  My teacher has helped me out multiple times but I still can't pass data through the following equation below.  I'm trying to get certain elements of array to get pushed into a new function if only they pass a test within the function.  Please have a look and thank you for your input.  An explanation as to why I get an empty array and resources to further my understanding would be appreciated.

```
// EACH DEFINITION
function each (collection, callback) {
    for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i ++){
    callback(collection[i]);
  }
}


// VARIABLE DECLARATION
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var isEven = function (num) {
  return num % 2 === 0;
};

// IMPLEMENT DEFINITION
function implement(array, test){ // array = myArray, test = isEven
  var arr = [];
  each(array, function(item){
    test(item);
  });
    if(test(array)){
      arr.push(array);

    }

  return arr;
}

// IMPLEMENT INVOCATION

implement(myArray, isEven);
```

Comment: Why are you pushing the result outside of the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// EACH DEFINITION
function each (collection, callback, results) {
  for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i ++){
    callback(collection[i]);
  }
  console.log(results);
}


// VARIABLE DECLARATION
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var isEven = function (num, array) {
  return num % 2 === 0;
};

// IMPLEMENT DEFINITION
function implement(array, test){ // array = myArray, test = isEven
  var arr = [];
  function filter (item) {
    if (test(item)) {
      arr.push(item);
    }
  }
  each(array, filter, arr);
  // If you return arr here, it will still be empty. You must pass it to functions it is being operated on.
}

// IMPLEMENT INVOCATION

implement(myArray, isEven);
```

Not only are you trying to push to arr outside of your loop, but you're trying to return arr before it has gained any values.

Answer (score 3):

You are building `arr` outside the `each()` loop.

I would think your code would be like this:

```
// IMPLEMENT DEFINITION
function implement(array, test){ // array = myArray, test = isEven
  var arr = [];
  each(array, function(item){
    if(test(item)) {
        arr.push(item);
    }
  });

  return arr;
}
```

Though in this case there is no reason for your `implement()` filtering function at all, since javascript Array prototype already has a [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.  You could simplify your call to this:

```
var filteredArray = myArray.filter(isEven);
```

Though you might also then want to change your isEven definition to be more correct as:

```
var isEven = function (num, index, array) {
```

In your case you don't need to work with the last two parameters.

Comment: Being right pedantic but I think you mean JavaScript not java.

Comment: @ste2425 Indeed I do :)

Answer (score 0):

Two points:

First, **your implementation of callback functions is correct.** As far as the concept of callbacks goes, you are calling and passing the functions correctly.

However, **your `implement()` function probably has a bug.** You are not pushing to `arr` until **after** `each()` has already been called:

```js
function implement(array, test) { // array = myArray, test = isEven
    var arr = [];
    each(array, function(item) {
        result = test(item);
    });

    // This block should be in the loop itself
    // It should also refer to item, not array
    if (test(array)) {
        arr.push(array);
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Try this fix based on the code you provided:

```js
// EACH DEFINITION
function each(collection, callback) {
  for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    callback(collection[i]);
  }
}


// VARIABLE DECLARATION
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var isEven = function(num) {
  return num % 2 === 0;
};

// IMPLEMENT DEFINITION
function implement(array, test) { // array = myArray, test = isEven
  var arr = [];
  each(array, function(item) {
    if (test(item)) {
      arr.push(item)
    }
  });
  
  if (test(array)) {
    arr.push(array);

  }

  return arr;
}

// IMPLEMENT INVOCATION

var result = implement(myArray, isEven);
console.log(result); // For snippet results
```

Answer (score 0):

Your callback, as you defined it, is

```
function(item){
  test(item);
}
```

this will only call `test` on each `item` and that's it. Since you want to take it further and add `item` to `arr` if `test` returns true, you should put that checking code inside the callback as well, making it

```
function(item){
  if (test(item)) {
    arr.push(item);
  }
}
```

so that this function will be called for each of the item.

Also, this part

```
if(test(array)){
  arr.push(array);
}
```

is incorrect because you are passing a whole array into isEven when isEven is expecting a number. `test(array)` will always return false; that's why your `arr` is empty.

Modifying your code to work as you wanted, it would be

```
// IMPLEMENT DEFINITION
function implement(array, test){ // array = myArray, test = isEven
  var arr = [];
  each(array, function(item){
    if (test(item)) {
      arr.push(item);
    }
  });

  return arr;
}
```

Resources wise, there are callbacks tutorial widely available online, as well as best practices. You can easily find one that suits you best by googling.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the entire issue here is in the implementation section you denote. All of the other code looks adequate.

> ```
> each(array, function(item){
>    test(item);
> });
> ```

Alright, first let's examine this piece of code. You are making a call to your each function, which will use the callback anonymous function defined here as shown.

However, if you were to look at the each function itself, there is no return (which means it returns undefined by default). There is also no modification being done in each. As a result, this set of code has no effect on the execution of the code, and from certain advanced compilation technique may actually be removed by the V8 engine in chrome if that was being used.

This means the only aspect of your code which is executing is

```
var arr = [];
if(test(array)){
  arr.push(array);

}
return arr;
```

At this point, test is still the `isEven` function, so you are basically asking this

```
if(array % 2 === 0) arr.push(array);
```

Arrays in JavaScript behave interestingly when used in conditional statements, and in this situation the array essentially has toString called on it (more in depth here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10556035/1026459 , but basically when you have object === number then it will attempt to use toPrimitive on the object which results in a string), which makes it

```
if("1,2,3" % 2 === 0)
```

which is false. As a result `arr` is unchanged, and returned in its original state of `[]`.