# Var's boolean value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs

I am not so expert in JavaScript and I am wonder if there is a way to test the boolean value of a variable in javascript.

In Python I can do this:

```
>>>list_var = []
>>>bool(list_var)
False  # This is the boolean value of a empty list
>>>
```

And if I try get an element in JS that does not exist, i.e:

```
document.getElementById('b-advanced')
[]  // This is what returns
```

Is there a way to test the expression above as boolean without using an `if...` statement?

**EDIT**

I think I need to point something.

This is the full expression I use:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('b-advanced'))
```

Comment: `getElementById` would never return an array. It either returns a DOM element or `null`.

Comment: Well, I am using that expression inside a `angular.element()` function.

Comment: How does that make any difference?

Comment: You are rigth, they don't return the same. http://postimg.org/image/wix57vk55/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `!!` in front which will return its boolean status.

```
!![] // true
!!null // false
```

Comment: So, an empty array is equivalent to `true`?

Comment: Correct! See [Conflicting boolean values of an empty Javascript Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226101/conflicting-boolean-values-of-an-empty-javascript-array) for a great explanation of this :)

Comment: This is really unexpected for me. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: If you found this answer to be helpful, please consider accepting it. Learn more about accepting answers [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: I think this is the simplest way. No functions, no if statements.

Answer (score 2):

There is not. The best you can do is `list_var.length === 0`. For a full test, you'd want to test as follows

```
// Return true if arg is an array or string containing at least one item
function isTrueness(arg) {
    return !!(arg && arg.length > 0);
}

angular.element(isTrueness(document.getElementById('b-advanced')));
```

Comment: this a good approach. I come from python and does not make sense for me that an empty array is equivalent to true.

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = Boolean(document.getElementById('b-advanced'));
```

[Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) is a wrapper for boolean values.

Answer (score 0):

you can test to see what type a variable is by using `typeof` so for example:

```
var myVar = true;
if (typeof myVar === "boolean") console.log("It is a boolean");
```

Comment: Note that, for some reason, the OP specifically wants to avoid using an if statement. However, I'm not sure this is a possibility. Anyway, if(`emptyVar`) will equate to false if the variable is empty by the various loose definitions JS employs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not exactly what I am asking for. In JS this: `[]` is equivalent to `false`?

Comment: I see... you're using getElementyById to get that value. Which as pointed out by someone else, would only return either `null` or a DOM element so i'm not sure in which scenario it would even return an array which is what `[]` is in JS

Comment: @Gocht: every object is "truthy" in JavaScript, so no.

Comment: are you maybe trying to get the text or an attribute of the element?

Comment: I edited the question with the full expression I use to get that empty array.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, an empty list is false.  In Javascript, an empty array is true.  You can mimic this by saying `myArray.length && myArray`.  If `myArray` is empty, then its length is zero and the expression is false.  If `myArray` isn’t empty, then Javascript returns the second operand, just like Python.