# $("#myElement").length vs. !!$("myElement") to check if the dom element exists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I need to check if a certain dom element exists or not. I saw other posts which suggests `length` property to check that. That works fine. But It works even without `length` property. For example:

```
!!$("#myElement");        // true
!!$("#myElement").length; // true
```

Both the ways return same value. So is it ok to not use `length` property to check if the element exists?

Comment: Have you considered testing this with an element that you know to not exist (i.e. length returns 0)? The results may surprise you.

Comment: In most code, I see if ($("#myElement").length) {}, because if there is no length then it will evaluate to false and if there is length, it'll evaluate to true.

Comment: You are getting a false positive with `$("#myElement")` as it doesn't care if the element exists. jQuery will ALWAYS return a jQuery object with any matched elements inside, hence always check `.length` to see if there is actually elements inside. Feel free to take a look at ► [**https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/**](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/)

Answer (score 0):

No, *always* use `length`.

Your logic here is flawed as a jQuery object is never empty or null, it always returns an object even if no element is selected, hence you cannot reliably coerce it to a boolean to see if the selector matched any elements.

```js
console.log(!!$('#exists')); // should be true
console.log(!!$('#doesNotExist')); // should be false
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="exists"></div>
```

As you can see above, both tests return `true`.

Comment: You are right `!![]` returns true. Can I use `!!$("#myElement")[0]` ?

Comment: You can, but don't. The `length` property is the accepted norm.

Comment: I was curious why does `!![]` return true? Isn't an empty array supposed to be falsy?

Comment: Accessing a jQuery object by index returns the underlying Element object (not an array) and that Element will be `null` when no element is found, hence the boolean coercion works.

Comment: I understand when used with index like `$('#doesNotExist')[index]` what I dont understand is why is an empty array considered truely in js.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. The answer is that JS's data typing was written by a drunk on a Friday afternoon. For a better explanation, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4226263/519413